# BLUP formula for random coefficient models, in form that allows for convenient derivatives WRT loss function

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, gradient-descent, blup

In [*Semiparametric Regression*](https://ideas.repec.org/b/cup/cbooks/9780521780506.html), Ruppert et al assert that the BLUP for $U_i$ in the model

$$
\begin{equation}
y_{it} = \beta_0 + U_i + \beta_1x_{it} + \epsilon_{it}
\end{equation}
$$

reduces to 
$$
\tilde{U}_i = \frac{n_i\sigma_u^2}{\sigma_\epsilon^2+n_i\sigma_u^2}\left(\bar{y}_i-\bar{x}_i\beta\right)
$$
They cite [this book](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470073713.html), which I don't have access to...

**How is this derived?**  I can see how it simplifies to the econometric fixed effects estimator when $\sigma_u \rightarrow \infty$, because the fraction would approach 1, which would make the individual intercept equal to the group-wise average residual.

This formulation has a convenient derivative of the variance terms WRT to a (L2-penalizable) squared-error loss function.  Assuming I remember my calculus, it is
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \sigma^2_u} = -2\hat\epsilon(\bar{y} - \bar{x}_i\beta)\left(\frac{n_i}{\sigma^2_\epsilon + n_i\sigma_u^2}+\sigma^2_u\right)
$$

Now consider a simple random coefficients model:
$$
y_{it} = \beta_0 + U_{1i} + \beta_1x_{it} + U_{2i}x_{it} + \epsilon_{it}
$$
where 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
U_1\\
U_2\\
\epsilon
\end{array}\right]\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\sigma_{U_1}^2 & \rho_{12} & 0\\
\rho_{12} &\sigma_{U_2}^2 &  0\\
0&0& \sigma^2_\epsilon\\
\end{array}\right]\right)
$$

and where $U_{2i}$ is $N \times 1$ and is multiplied element-wise by $x_{it}$

**What is the equivalent expression for predicting the random effects $\tilde U_1$ and $\tilde U_2$ (given estimated parameters) and how is it derived?**

There is a matrix form for this.  Following [Simon Wood](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584884746), the model is first formulated as 
$$
\mathbf{y = X\beta+Z}b+\epsilon
$$
While the book doesn't make it super-explicit, I'm taking it that the dimension of $\mathbf{Z}$ would be $N \times gk$, where $g$ is the number of groups, and $k$ is the number of random terms.  In my example, it'd be the Khatri-Rao product of the group indicator on a vector of ones, concatenated to a KR product of the group indicator on the regressor $x_{it}$.

$b$ is thus a $gk\times 1$ vector, with the BLUPs for different terms stacked on each other.  (Is this right?  would appreciate confirmation)

In this formulation, the BLUP is then 
$$
\hat{b} = \mathbf{\left(\tilde{Z}^T\tilde{Z}\right)^{-1}\tilde{Z}^T\left(\tilde y-\tilde X\hat\beta\right)}
$$
Where
$$
\tilde{y} = \left[\begin{array}{c}\mathbf{y}\\\mathbf{0}\end{array}\right], \tilde{X} = \left[\begin{array}{c}\mathbf{X}\\\mathbf{0}\end{array}\right], \tilde{Z} = \left[\begin{array}{c}\mathbf{Z}\\\mathbf{B}\end{array}\right]
$$
Where $\mathbf{B^TB} = \psi^{-1}\sigma^2$, where $\psi$ is the covariance of the random effects and $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $\epsilon$.

Since $\psi$ is $k\times k$ however, $\mathbf{B}$ can't be conformable with $\mathbf{Z}$, which is $n\times gk$.  So there is a place where I am lost.  Any help?

Anyway, I'm not sure that this formulation of the problem is helpful, becuase ultimately I'm thinking about mixed models in the context of [estimating them by gradient descent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317500/mixed-model-by-gradient-descent).

**Is there a clean way to compute $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \psi}$** (and ultimately the gradient with respect to the loss function) **from this matrix formulation?  Or can I derive an expression for computing each $g\times 1$ subset of $\mathbf{b}$ individually,** for each random term, as in the second equation above?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what does BLUP stand for? Best Linear Unbiased <something>?

Comment: @ssdecontrol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_linear_unbiased_prediction